# Работоспособность password_hash в связке с sha512?

Tags: php

Нормально ли будет работать **password_hash(PASSWORD_DEFAULT)** в связке с **openssl_digest($salt, 'sha512')**? Не будет ли коллизий и других ошибок? Нормально ли будет воспринимать БД. Какую рекомендуется  установить кодировку, для колонки под это значение, Windows-1251?

Answer (score 1):

> Нормально ли будет работать password_hash(PASSWORD_DEFAULT) в связке с openssl_digest($salt, 'sha512')

Да, но согласно документации [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) , начиная с версии PHP 7.0.0 опция для передачи сгенерированной соли считается устаревшей и будет убрана в будущих версиях, поэтому рекомендуется оставить генерирование соли самой функции `password_hash`. Также сгенерированную соль не надо хранить в отдельном месте, вся информация об использованной алгоритме и соли содержется уже в хеше, но для проверки введенного пользователем пароля с хешем необходимо будет воспользоваться функцией [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php)

> Не будет ли коллизий и других ошибок?

Возможность коллизий для паролей крайне мала, если для авторизации используется еще и имя пользователя, то коллизии вообще не стоит рассматривать.

> Нормально ли будет воспринимать БД. Какую рекомендуется установить кодировку, для колонки под это значение, Windows-1251?

БД - это просто хранилище данных и хеш будет восприниматься также как и другие строки. Кодировку специально для поля с хешем выбирать не надо, ставьте ту, которая используется повсеместно в проекте.